# Why doesn't Super User have a "top percentage" link in the user profile like Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow it is sometimes fun to look at stats and see how close I am to catching [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).  I can just go to my profile and click the "top percentage" link to see how I rank.  The same link does not appear on my Super User page and I was wondering why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because we're not conceited.

Comment: @KronoS like SO users?

Comment: That was more of a passing joke, but in reality, reputation doesn't have as much of a precedence here as it does on SO. Don't get me wrong, users like to increase their rep, but it's not as much of a competition as SO.

Comment: Speak for yourself! All the rep for meeeee!! :-D

Comment: Looking at the [privilege milestones](http://superuser.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone): You're in the top 5% with 200 all time reputation. You're in the top 1% with 1000 reputation. [A single up vote (+5 rep) or confirmed suggested edit (+2) elevates you to the *top 1% this week* (if the reference is the total number of users).](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser) SU can offer very little progression since it's a much smaller site, less than one 10th of the users.